# Example of a a non-compact closed subset of a Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology

Can some one please provide a clear concrete example of this? I understand that if a subset of Hausdorff space is compact it is closed and that if the Hausdorff space is compact the converse will be true. I just am having a hard time with why this is not true for general Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is a non compact closed subset of the reals.

Comment: Ugh , thanks sets like that still get me because I forget to check that the r complement is open. Hence I get caught up on the interval notation [,) and think its not closed automatically.

Comment: If X  is a non-compact Hausdorff space then X is a closed non-compact subset of X.

Answer (score 1):

Think of unbounded Hausdorff spaces. Consider the real numbers, and the subspace of non-negative reals.

Answer (score 0):

(1). If $X$ is a non-compact space then $X$ is a closed non-compact subset of $X.$

(2). If we are interested in closed $proper$ subsets: Suppose that $X\ne \phi$ and that  every closed proper subset of  $X$ is  compact . Let $C$ be any open cover of $X.$ Take $p\in X$ and $S\in C$ such that $p\in S.$ Then $X\setminus S$ is a proper closed subset of $X$ so it is compact. Now $C$ is an open cover of $X \setminus S,$ so let $D$ be a finite subset of $C$ such that $\cup D\supset X\setminus  S.$ Then $\{S\}\cup D$ is a finite subset of $C$ that covers $X.$ Therefore X is compact.

From this we see that if a space is not compact, it must have a closed non-compact proper subset.

Comment: The role of the Hausdorff property is in the opposite direction: If $Y$ is a compact subset of the Hausdorff space $X$ then $Y$ is closed in $X .$  A space which is $T_1$ but not $T_2$ may be compact and have a non-closed compact subset